# Error while import csv file datetime value into Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, csv, casting

Error:

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Specified cast is not valid.'

Error occurs on this line of code:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateTime", (DateTime)importRow["DateTime"]);
```

Full code:

```
using (SqlConnection conn =New SqlConnection(@"Data Source=BL03\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=HDB; User Id=sa; Password=00"))
{
    conn.Open();

    foreach (DataRow importRow in S2P5.Rows)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand ("INSERT INTO S2P5 (DateTime, Miliseconds, MachineAutoStartStop, Pressure)" + 
                                         "VALUES (@DateTime, @Miliseconds, @MachineAutoStartStop, @Pressure)", conn);
      
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateTime", (DateTime)importRow["DateTime"]);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Miliseconds", importRow["Miliseconds"]);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MachineAutoStartStop", importRow["MachineAutoStartStop"]);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pressure", importRow["Pressure"]);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: what value you have in `importRow["DateTime"]` ?

Comment: Please don't spam tags to trick people into viewing your question. This issue has nothing at all to do with the C language or SSMS or WinForms.

Comment: VALUE : 25/10/2022  12:00:00 AM

Answer (score 0):

You can't cast something as a type it isn't already. Casting is NOT converting. If you're reading from a CSV file then everything is a `string`. You need to CONVERT that `string` to a `DateTime`. There are various ways to do that. If the data is guaranteed to be correct then you can use `DateTime.Parse` or `.ParseExact`. If you need to validate as well then use `.TryParse` or `.TryParseExact`. You should be converting the numeric data to numbers as well. I suspect that you have Boolean data there too, so you should be converting that as well.